# Helper scan fails over 90000 documents?

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, scroll, limit, helper

Because of the limit of search in elasticsearch python module I starter using scroll to access more than 10000 documents. I didn't test if there was a limit for the scroll because it was working OK. But a couple of days ago I got over 100000 documents as a result of a query and my implementation of the scroll started failing with:

> SearchContextMissingException [No search context found for id [568]

I thought that my code was failing somehow although I couldn't see the problem. But while googleing I found the helper scan and I decided to use it since it does the work of implementing the scroll without any worries about my code having a bug. But when using scan with a large amount of data ( around 90000) I keep getting the previous error. Has anybody seen the same behaviour before? Is this expected? Is there any workaround I can use to avoid this problem without splitting the query?

Best regards,

Ruben

Answer (score 1):

Is is not really clear if you set the size of the scroll to 900000 or bigger or if you are just looping over more documents by keep calling the scroll. What could happen is that handling the data takes to much time before you return to the scroll. The context is kept a default amount of time that you can configure using the scroll parameter as described in the following url:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am looping over more documents by keep calling the scroll. And I use the scroll parameter with different values (up to 5 minutes) and it still fails.